# how to solve Travelling salesman problem algorithm by adding additional trucks?

Tags: python, graph

Can someone help me with this problem.
Firstly this is the question
"Vaccine distribution is a challenging problem. The conditions for transport and storage of novel vaccines mean only one transport truck currently exists and must visit several of the main cities of the UK for 12 hours each to allow for the public to be vaccinated. Find an optimal route for the truck to take through these cities.
If additional trucks could be developed for
transportation how much would this lower
the overall time cost?"

the total number of cities are 15. How to add 1 more truck to it. so the total number of trucks will be 2 and how to add more truck to reduce the overall time.

I want to add additional truck and how to implement the 12 hours time for each?
below is my code that i have worked out.

```
***
# Doing our imports
import random, numpy, math, copy, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Randomly create some cities (these could be specified in a list of 2-d lists like a 2-d array)
#cities = [random.sample(range(100), 2) for x in range(15)];
# Fix cities to be a set list:
cities = [[56, 15], [62, 34], [46, 49], [89, 59], [3, 44], [13, 25], [13, 90], [33, 87], [87, 58], [99, 24], [19, 4], [11, 28], [4, 0], [70, 32], [80, 31]]
tour = random.sample(range(15),15);
print('Initial Guess:\n')
plt.plot([cities[tour[i % 15]][0] for i in range(16)], [cities[tour[i % 15]][1] for i in range(16)], 'xr-');
plt.show()

for temperature in numpy.logspace(0,5,num=100000)[::-1]:
  [i,j] = sorted(random.sample(range(15),2));
  newTour =  tour[:i] + tour[j:j+1] +  tour[i+1:j] + tour[i:i+1] + tour[j+1:];
  if math.exp( ( sum([ math.sqrt(sum([(cities[tour[(k+1) % 15]][d] - cities[tour[k % 15]][d])**2 for d in [0,1] ])) for k in [j,j-1,i,i-1]]) - sum([math.sqrt(sum([(cities[newTour[(k+1) % 15]][d] - cities[newTour[k % 15]][d])**2 for d in [0,1] ])) for k in [j,j-1,i,i-1]])) / temperature) > random.random():
    tour = copy.copy(newTour);
print('\nFinal Path:\n')
plt.plot([cities[tour[i % 15]][0] for i in range(16)], [cities[tour[i % 15]][1] for i in range(16)], 'xb-');
plt.show()
***
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the time spent at every city is the same ( 12 hours ) the total time for a route is

```
city count * 12 + travel time on chosen route
```

Since city count * 12 is constant, the problem for one truck is the familiar calculation of a minimum spanning tree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

For more than one truck, the graph of cities must be partitioned into the same number of sub-graphs so as to minimize the the maximum travel time through the sub-graphs.  This requires the application of cluster analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Assuming that the travel time between cities is proportional to the pythagorian distance between them and that the name of the city at { 56, 15} is "c56x15" here is a minimum spanning tree for all your cities, withc total cost 261

[image]

Adding a second truck and using the KMeans clustering algorithm I get

cluster1 total cost 67

[image]

cluster2 total cost 184

[image]

Comment: i have looked into these but did not get it. can you please comment the code

Comment: Did you look at the wikipaedia links?.  They describe the algorithms you need to solve your problem and provide links to further information and examples of implementations.

Comment: Note that to tackle this problem, we need to know the travel time ( = distance ) between the cities.  Looking at your code, I cannot spot where you specify this.  It looks like you have two dimensional locations ( cities = [[56, 15], [62, 34],... )  Are you assuming that the travel times between cities are equivalent to the Pythagorean distance between them?

Comment: @hashir did not reply, so I have gone ahead with the Pythagorean assumption and added sample results to my answer.

Comment: The C++ code for the sample results is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/vaccineTruck